# Select the checkboxes through loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How i can i select the check boxes through loop ?

For example i have 4 check boxes and if is select the 3rd check-box then 1st and 2nd also selected and if i select 4th check-box then 1st, 2nd, and 3rd also got selected.

Any hint about this in jquery , java script or any other language?

help will be appreciated...........

HTML Code

```
<form>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3"> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4"> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5"> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: @Pranav i tried to do this through foreach loop but i show the number of chechboxes checked but not select the previous check boxes

Comment: @Mehar just putting it out there that the answer you've accepted is poor quality. I'm not sure how it gained so many upvotes. Consider this situation: tab to a checkbox and press <kbd>space</kbd>, with the answer you've accepted, only that one checkbox will be checked. My answer doesn't have this problem, and involves much less processing as it doesn't require an unnecessary loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16730225/1317805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("input:checkbox").on("click",function(){
    if(this.checked)
    $(this).parent().prevAll().each(function(){
        $("input:checkbox",this).attr("checked",true);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/urau8/4/)

To un-check the all checked ones add this below code

```
if(this.checked==false)
    $(this).parent().each(function(){
         $("input").attr("checked",false);
    });
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/urau8/5/)**

Comment: @sachin i want to uncheck all the check-boxes if user un-check even one check-box

Comment: change the if(this.checked) to if(this.checked==false)  and change the last line to   $("input:checkbox",this).attr("checked",false);

Comment: @Sowmya it means u r taking only 1 min to solve this question.so u r great

Comment: @Mehar Check the updated [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/urau8/5/)  and sachin Thnks

Comment: You don't need an `each()` loop at all, and this will only fire when a checkbox is clicked (not changed through key press, for instance). You can do the same thing with less code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16730225/1317805

Comment: @Mehar if you're going to stick with this answer, you need to change a few things: 1. `prop()` should be used for boolean values, not `attr()`; 2. change `$('input...').on('click', func...)` to `$('form').on('click', 'input...', func...)` to make it faster; 3. remove the `this.checked` if statement as this can replace the `true` with that instead; 4. replace the `click` handler with a `change` handler, otherwise you're able to check the checkboxes with nothing happening.

Comment: use .prop() instead of .attr() :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and I don't think finding another way for the same solution should opt for downvote. Anyways I dont mind...:)

Comment: @Sowmya the problem is that your answer is full of holes. `each()` isn't needed and wastes time; `prop()` is used for boolean values, not `attr()` - this has been the case since jQuery 1.6; you're only detecting the `click` event, meaning this won't fire when the checkbox is changed through something which isn't a click; the `this.checked` if statement is unnecessary. Sorry to say it, but I'm a little confused as to why this was upvoted at all in the first place, let alone accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how that other answer gained so much popularity. It's far from perfect and will only fire when a checkbox is changed through a click.

Here's a much simpler and more semantic solution without even needing an `each()` loop, which will work without the checkbox having to be `clicked` (i.e. having its value changed with a keypress):

```
$('form').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]:checked', function(){
    $(this).parent().prevAll('div').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked",true);
});
```

This [`on('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method only fires when a checkbox is checked. It then finds all previous dividers and within them sets any checkboxes to checked by making use of jQuery's [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/5x82K/2/).

Alternatively if you want to both check *and* uncheck:

```
$('form').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
    $(this).parent().prevAll('div').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked",this.checked);
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/5x82K/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way using javascript:-

```
if (document.getElementById('id4').checked)

{
document.getElementById('id3').checked = true;
document.getElementById('id2').checked = true;
document.getElementById('id1').checked = true;

}
```

and so on.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : (*you don't need to loop through checkboxes*)

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change',function(){
    var i = $('input').index(this);
    if(this.checked){
      $("input:lt("+i+")").prop('checked',true);
    }
    else{
      $("input:lt("+i+")").prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/eqPG2/

Comment: @Mehar... yes..try the demo

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, both to check and uncheck:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change",function(){
    ichecked=this.checked;
    $target = ichecked?$(this).parent().prevAll():$(this).parent().nextAll();
    $target.find('input:checkbox').prop("checked",ichecked);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZhFg/)